Fabric Notebook - default Lakehouse link with Azure DevOps Integration
I have a problem with deploying Notebooks from my Dev enviroment to my prod enviroment.
I use Azure DevOps Git and have the challenge that the default Lakehouse and Workspace ID change in the deployment. I found some solutions but none is really working well for me.
I looked into the configue-magick command, but I could not figure out if I can use variables, I'd set in a cell before, in the configure command.
Then I checked Deployment Pipelines in Fabric, but it seems like that's a little in concurence to the Git integration I already work with.
Who handeled, having one notebook that takes one Lakehouse in Dev and another in Prod, and how?
How can my my Notebook use Lakehouse A in Dev and Lakehouse B in Prod. (each Lakehouse is in a separate workspace)

I achieved what you described with deployment pipelines and deployment rules. anyway If you want to stick with Azure DevOps you can look into the Fabric APIs to see if there is any endpoint that allows you to change lakehouse ids.
